# Entity Framework 6.1.1 Code First create unreadable table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have some problem with this code:

```
class Program
{
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());

         using (var context = new MyContext()) {
            var newType = new SysType { Name = "New Name" };
            context.SysTypes.Add(newType);
            context.SaveChanges();            
         }

         using (var context = new MyContext()) {
            Console.WriteLine(context.SysTypes.FirstOrDefault());
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }

   public class SysType
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; } 
   }

   public class MyContext : DbContext
   {
      public MyContext() : base("name=MyDb") { }      
      public DbSet<SysType> SysTypes { get; set; }      
   }
```

During execution the program an exception happens:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException"
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExeption: Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

But the database does get created (to post images not allowed for me)

![SQL Server Object Explorer view]

If try to query a table's data, an exception is thrown

![Exception if query table data]

If I create tables manually using a SQL script, then table query is successful.

Аfter many hours, I realized that this is because of the name of the table.

If change table name - all work perfectly.

My question is: why does my table name `SysType` throw an exception? Аnd is there any other names of the tables that cause a similar problems?

I will be glad to hear the answer to my question

Update: Model First approach - the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the entity you have will be created as `dbo.SysTypes` where as it is an existing system table in the database that is also [`dbo.SysTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175109.aspx).

Your entity will be generated as `dbo.SysTypes` because `dbo` is the default schema name when generating a table and the `SysType` will be pluralized into `SysTypes` by [`PluralizingTableNameConvention`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx).

The solution is to configure manually the generated table name, you can either using attribute:

```
[TableAttribute("Application_SysTypes")]
```

or using fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SysType>().ToTable("Application_SysTypes")`
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not pay attention to the name pluralization

Answer (score 0):

systypes is a system table in SQL Server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260587(v=sql.80).aspx

A list of all system tables: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260604(v=sql.80).aspx